# Chore app with advanced scheduling tools

Tags: android

I'm looking for an app to share chore scheduling between me and my wife on Android (and a web client would be a plus), with the following features:

- Able to schedule chores many different ways (first of the month, every other week), over multiple days. For example, I do laundry every other weekend, but it could be done Friday through Sunday.
- Swap chores
- Shared shopping list is a plus

We tried Picniic, but its scheduling tools leave a lot to be desired and has no web client.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it too difficult. Your first two bullet points can be accomplished in any calendar app if you share each others 'Chores Me' and 'Chores You' calendars for editing. Swapping is than as simple as changing the calendar for an entry.<sup>*</sup>

The shopping list can be made in any list app, e.g. [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/)

<sup>* If you are already using an app that supports different calendars, just add two.</sup>